# node.js - stream file without saving it temporarily

Tags: node.js, file-upload, stream

So this is my setup

I have a client from which files are uploaded to the node.js server (serverA) and from there I want to stream the files to another server (serverB) **without** saving the file temporarily (on serverA).

What is the simplest and the best way to achieve this?

I am able to upload the file to serverA but I don't want the temporary file to be stored.

**Update:**

its a simple ajax file uplaod to (severA)... The idea is to transfer byte-wise so that even if the connection goes off, you can read it back from that particular byte.

I am using express.js on serverA and backbone.js is the client using which I do the ajax uploads. For now there's no connection between A and B as such, they communicate through endpoints. serverA is running on port 4000 and serverB on port 5000. I want to somehow pipe the file from serverA to an endpoint on serverB.

Comment: How are you getting that file?  How are you pushing the file?  What do you do in case of connection problems?

Comment: its a simple ajax file uplaod to (severA)... The idea is to transfer byte-wise so that even if the connection goes off, you can read it back from that particular byte.

Comment: Can you add some more details?  So, your Node.js application on Server A is using what to host this AJAX script?  The built-in http server?  What about Server B?  What are you using for the connection between the two?

Comment: I am using express.js on serverA and backbone.js is the client using which I do the ajax uploads. For now there's no connection as such. serverA is running on port 4000 and serverB on port 5000. I want somehow pipe the file from serverA to an endpoint on serverB.

Comment: The easiest way is to mount the remote file system.  Then, you don't even have to write any code for it.  Is this an option for you?

Comment: nope! won't be able to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since HttpRequest is a stream, you could use the `request` module to pipe the current request into the other endpoint inside your express route:

```
app.post('myroute', function (req, res) {
    var request = require('request');
    req.pipe(request.post('/my/path:5000')).pipe(res);
});
```

Would that approach work?

Comment: Yeah I used the same approach. Since I also had to send the content-range and content-length, I stripped the fs.write from node-formidable and replaced it with res.write to the server B...