# Node.JS - Post upload file without saving

Tags: angularjs, node.js, file-upload, sails.js

Thanks ahead of time for the help.

I have an angular front end with a Node.JS (sails framework) backend.  I want to take an uploaded pdf file from the front end and use that uploaded file to do a POST request to a 3rd party service without saving the file temporarily.

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use `.pipe()`

Comment: Thanks @remus.  Can you elaborate? I'm reading up on how to implement pipe with streams but I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Take a look at `request` module - it can receive a pipe from an express route - you can pipe the request straight over to your destination.

Comment: possible duplicate of [node.js - stream file without saving it temporarily](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358619/node-js-stream-file-without-saving-it-temporarily)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up uploading the file using [skipper](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper), POSTing the file to a 3rd party, and then deleting the temporary file using [fs.unlink](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system). Works cleanly for my current needs.